# Mediawiki disable Talk pages from public viewing

Tags: mediawiki

I recently started using Mediawiki and I am currently on version 1.17.

I would like to disable Talk namespace pages from viewing from public. I already disabled UserCreation as I would like only me to edit the pages. So, I am basically using it as a CMS.

My question is, how can I disable view access for Talk pages for public.

PS: I already disabled the tab bar, so the Discussion link doesn't appear, but if some one manually types Talk:PageName, it opens up. This is what I want to disable.

Comment: See [Restrict viewing of certain specific pages](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Preventing_access#Restrict_viewing_of_certain_specific_pages) in the MediaWiki manual.

Answer (score 2):

This will only *hide* the talk pages. People can still use them by going to the URL directly.

In addition add this to your LocalSettings.php to prevent people from editing talk pages:

```
for($i = 1;$i < 12; $i += 2) {
  $wgNamespaceProtection[$i] = 'noedit';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MediaWiki is not designed for this kind of usage since Talk pages are inherent to the system. One possible way for you would be to hide the talk page links by editing your skin.

The following CSS will hide the top talk links:

```
li#ca-talk {
 display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In LocalSettings.php set:

`$wgDisableAnonTalk = false;`

According to the [Manual:$wgDisableAnonTalk](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgDisableAnonTalk) this 'disables links to talk pages of anonymous users (IPs) in listings on special pages'.

Comment: That's about talks in "User talk" namespace, not "Talk".

Answer (score -1):

Hide the talk pages like in the other answers and additionally disable access to the talk pages by blacklisting URLs matching that pattern in your web server or WAF.

Comment: That should rather be a comment, not an answer.